# Oracle SQL: How to select only ID‘s which are member in specific groups?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I want to select only those ID‘s which are in specific groups.
For example:

```
ID  GroupID
1   11
1   12
2   11
2   12
2   13
```

Here I want to select the ID's which are in the groups 11 and 12 but in no other groups.
So the result should show just the ID 1 and not 2.
Can someone provide a SQL for that?
I tried it with

```
SELECT ID FROM table
WHERE GroupID = 11 AND GroupID = 12 AND GroupID != 13;
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: In _both_ 11 _and_ 12? Or is just one of 11 _or_ 12 fine too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having  min(groupID) = 11 and max(groupID) = 12
```

This `having` condition ensures that the given id belongs to `groupID`s 11 *and* 12, and to no other group. This works because 11 and 12 are sequential numbers.

Other options: if you want `id`s that belong to group 11 or 12 (not necessarily both), and to no other group, then:

```
having sum(case when groupId in (11, 12) then 1 end) = count(*)
```

If numbers are not sequential, and you want `id`s in both groups (necessarily) and in no other group:

```
having
    max(case when groupID = 11 then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when groupID = 12 then 1 end) = 1
    and max(case when groupID in (11, 12) then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    SELECT t.id FROM table t
where  exists(
    SELECT * FROM table
    where   group = 11 
    and  t.id = id
)
and exists(
    SELECT * FROM table
    where   group = 12
    and  t.id = id
)
and not exists(
    SELECT * FROM table
    where   group = 13
    and  t.id = id
)
group by t.id
```

Comment: This is very inefficient as it will use multiple table/index scans.

Comment: Just another solition not optimum one

Answer (score 1):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(case when groupid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when groupid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when groupid in (1, 2) then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` and a conditional `COUNT`:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE Group_ID WHEN 11 THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    COUNT( CASE Group_ID WHEN 12 THEN 1 END ) > 0
AND    COUNT( CASE WHEN Group_ID NOT IN ( 11, 12 ) THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

Or you can use collections:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF NUMBER(8,0);
```

and:

```sql
SELECT   id
FROM     table_name
GROUP BY id
HAVING   int_list( 11, 12 ) SUBMULTISET OF CAST( COLLECT( group_id ) AS int_list )
AND      CARDINALITY( CAST( COLLECT( group_id ) AS int_list )
                      MULTISET EXCEPT int_list( 11, 12 ) ) = 0
```

*(Using collections has the advantage that you can pass the collection of required values as a single bind parameter whereas using conditional aggregation is probably going to require dynamic SQL if you want to pass a variable number of items to the query.)*

Both output:

> ```
> | ID |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5576fbe51a868a699684045828849b52)*

Answer (score 0):

Use joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c11.ID
  FROM (SELECT ID FROM WORK_TABLE WHERE GROUPID = 11) c11
  INNER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM WORK_TABLE WHERE GROUPID = 12) c12
    ON c12.ID = c11.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID FROM WORK_TABLE WHERE GROUPID NOT IN (11, 12)) co
    ON co.ID = c11.ID
  WHERE co.ID IS NULL;
```

The `INNER JOIN` between the first two subqueries ensures that rows exist for both GROUPID 11 and 12, and the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `WHERE` verify that there are no rows for any other GROUPIDs.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a4699c394f09d0f05825ddfc7964aebd)